# Jenkins helm chart not updating plugins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I am having a problem with jenkins kubernetes pod that stopped working after the last pod restart (done by kubernetes).

So, I am having errors like this in my log:

```
2021-02-05 11:00:55.856+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins
2021-02-05 11:00:56.883+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Multibranch v2.22 (workflow-multibranch)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Multibranch (2.22)
 - Update required: Pipeline: Job (2.36) to be updated to 2.39 or higher
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:952)
    at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:549)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I can see that I should upgrade the version of `workflow-job` plugin to 2.39.

Jenkins is managed with helm. If I download the latest helm chart from S3, I can see it has a folder `jenkins` in it, where I can see `jenkins/values.yaml` looking like this:

```
# Default values for jenkins.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare name/value pairs to be passed into your templates.
# name: value

## Overrides for generated resource names
# See templates/_helpers.tpl
# nameOverride:
# fullnameOverride:

Master:
  Name: jenkins-master
  Image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  ImageTag: "lts"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
# ImagePullSecret: jenkins
  Component: "jenkins-master"
  NumExecutors: 0
  # configAutoReload requires UseSecurity is set to true:
  UseSecurity: true
  # SecurityRealm:
  # Optionally configure a different AuthorizationStrategy using Jenkins XML
  # AuthorizationStrategy: |-
  #    <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
  #      <denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  #    </authorizationStrategy>
  HostNetworking: false
  # When enabling LDAP or another non-Jenkins identity source, the built-in admin account will no longer exist.
  # Since the AdminUser is used by configAutoReload, in order to use configAutoReload you must change the
  # .Master.AdminUser to a valid username on your LDAP (or other) server.  This user does not need
  # to have administrator rights in Jenkins (the default Overall:Read is sufficient) nor will it be granted any
  # additional rights.  Failure to do this will cause the sidecar container to fail to authenticate via SSH and enter
  # a restart loop.  Likewise if you disable the non-Jenkins identity store and instead use the Jenkins internal one,
  # you should revert Master.AdminUser to your preferred admin user:
  AdminUser: admin
  # AdminPassword: <defaults to random>
  OwnSshKey: false
  # If CasC auto-reload is enabled, an SSH (RSA) keypair is needed.  Can either provide your own, or leave unconfigured\false to allow a random key to be auto-generated.
  # If you choose to use your own, you must upload your decrypted RSA private key (not the public key above) to a Kubernetes secret using the following command:
  # kubectl -n <namespace> create secret generic <helm_release_name> --dry-run --from-file=jenkins-admin-private-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa -o yaml |kubectl -n <namespace> apply -f -
  # Replace ~/.ssh/id_rsa in the above command with the path to your private key file and the <helm_release_name> and <namespace> placeholders to suit.
  RollingUpdate: {}
  # Ignored if Persistence is enabled
  # maxSurge: 1
  # maxUnavailable: 25%
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "50m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "2000m"
      memory: "4096Mi"
  # Environment variables that get added to the init container (useful for e.g. http_proxy)
  # InitContainerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # ContainerEnv:
  #   - name: http_proxy
  #     value: "http://192.168.64.1:3128"
  # Set min/max heap here if needed with:
  # JavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  # JenkinsOpts: ""
  # JenkinsUrl: ""
  # If you set this prefix and use ingress controller then you might want to set the ingress path below
  # JenkinsUriPrefix: "/jenkins"
  # Enable pod security context (must be `true` if RunAsUser or FsGroup are set)
  UsePodSecurityContext: true
  # Set RunAsUser to 1000 to let Jenkins run as non-root user 'jenkins' which exists in 'jenkins/jenkins' docker image.
  # When setting RunAsUser to a different value than 0 also set FsGroup to the same value:
  # RunAsUser: <defaults to 0>
  # FsGroup: <will be omitted in deployment if RunAsUser is 0>
  ServicePort: 8080
  # For minikube, set this to NodePort, elsewhere use LoadBalancer
  # Use ClusterIP if your setup includes ingress controller
  ServiceType: LoadBalancer
  # Master Service annotations
  ServiceAnnotations: {}
  # Master Custom Labels
  DeploymentLabels: {}
  #   foo: bar
  #   bar: foo
  # Master Service Labels
  ServiceLabels: {}
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: https
  # Put labels on jeknins-master pod
  PodLabels: {}
  # Used to create Ingress record (should used with ServiceType: ClusterIP)
  # HostName: jenkins.cluster.local
  # NodePort: <to set explicitly, choose port between 30000-32767
  # Enable Kubernetes Liveness and Readiness Probes
  # ~ 2 minutes to allow Jenkins to restart when upgrading plugins. Set ReadinessTimeout to be shorter than LivenessTimeout.
  HealthProbes: true
  HealthProbesLivenessTimeout: 90
  HealthProbesReadinessTimeout: 60
  HealthProbeReadinessPeriodSeconds: 10
  HealthProbeLivenessFailureThreshold: 12
  SlaveListenerPort: 50000
#  SlaveHostPort: 50000
  DisabledAgentProtocols:
    - JNLP-connect
    - JNLP2-connect
  CSRF:
    DefaultCrumbIssuer:
      Enabled: true
      ProxyCompatability: true
  CLI: false
  # Kubernetes service type for the JNLP slave service
  # SlaveListenerServiceType is the Kubernetes Service type for the JNLP slave service,
  # either 'LoadBalancer', 'NodePort', or 'ClusterIP'
  # Note if you set this to 'LoadBalancer', you *must* define annotations to secure it. By default
  # this will be an external load balancer and allowing inbound 0.0.0.0/0, a HUGE
  # security risk:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1341
  SlaveListenerServiceType: ClusterIP
  SlaveListenerServiceAnnotations: {}

  # Example of 'LoadBalancer' type of slave listener with annotations securing it
  # SlaveListenerServiceType: LoadBalancer
  # SlaveListenerServiceAnnotations:
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "True"
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges: "172.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8"

  # LoadBalancerSourcesRange is a list of allowed CIDR values, which are combined with ServicePort to
  # set allowed inbound rules on the security group assigned to the master load balancer
  LoadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
  # Optionally assign a known public LB IP
  # LoadBalancerIP: 1.2.3.4
  # Optionally configure a JMX port
  # requires additional JavaOpts, ie
  # JavaOpts: >
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=4000
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  #   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
  # JMXPort: 4000
  # Optionally configure other ports to expose in the Master container
  ExtraPorts:
  # - name: BuildInfoProxy
  #   port: 9000

  # List of plugins to be install during Jenkins master start
  OverwritePlugins: true
  InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.16.1
    - workflow-job:2.39
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - workflow-basic-steps:2.18
    - credentials-binding:1.23
    - job-dsl:1.76
    - git:4.2.2
    - parameterized-trigger:2.35.2
    - slack:2.34
    - global-slack-notifier:1.5
    - ansicolor:0.6.2
    - simple-theme-plugin:0.5.1
    - aws-bucket-credentials:1.0.0
    - aws-credentials:1.28
    - ssh-agent:1.17
    #      - blueocean:1.21.0
    - basic-branch-build-strategies:1.3.2
    - buildtriggerbadge:2.10
    - rebuild:1.31
    - ghprb:1.42.0
    - antisamy-markup-formatter:1.5
    - github-oauth:0.31
    - role-strategy:2.15

  # Enable to always override the installed plugins with the values of 'Master.InstallPlugins' on upgrade or redeployment.
  # OverwritePlugins: true
  # Enable HTML parsing using OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin (antisamy-markup-formatter), useful with ghprb plugin.
  # The plugin is not installed by default, please update Master.InstallPlugins.
  # EnableRawHtmlMarkupFormatter: true
  # Used to approve a list of groovy functions in pipelines used the script-security plugin. Can be viewed under /scriptApproval
  # ScriptApproval:
  #   - "method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText java.lang.String"
  #   - "new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic"
  # List of groovy init scripts to be executed during Jenkins master start
  InitScripts:
  #  - |
  #    print 'adding global pipeline libraries, register properties, bootstrap jobs...'
  # Kubernetes secret that contains a 'credentials.xml' for Jenkins
  # CredentialsXmlSecret: jenkins-credentials
  # Kubernetes secret that contains files to be put in the Jenkins 'secrets' directory,
  # useful to manage encryption keys used for credentials.xml for instance (such as
  # master.key and hudson.util.Secret)
  # SecretsFilesSecret: jenkins-secrets
  # Jenkins XML job configs to provision
  # Jobs:
  #   test: |-
  #     <<xml here>>

  # Below is the implementation of Jenkins Configuration as Code.  Add a key under ConfigScripts for each configuration area,
  # where each corresponds to a plugin or section of the UI.  Each key (prior to | character) is just a label, and can be any value.
  # Keys are only used to give the section a meaningful name.  The only restriction is they may only contain RFC 1123 \ DNS label
  # characters: lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens.  The keys become the name of a configuration yaml file on the master in
  # /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs (by default) and will be processed by the Configuration as Code Plugin.  The lines after each |
  # become the content of the configuration yaml file.  The first line after this is a JCasC root element, eg jenkins, credentials,
  # etc.  Best reference is https://<jenkins_url>/configuration-as-code/reference.  The example below creates a welcome message:
  JCasC:
    enabled: false
    PluginVersion: 1.5
    SupportPluginVersion: 1.5
    ConfigScripts:
      welcome-message: |
        jenkins:
          systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.

  Sidecars:
    configAutoReload:
      # If enabled: true, Jenkins Configuration as Code will be reloaded on-the-fly without a reboot.  If false or not-specified,
      # jcasc changes will cause a reboot and will only be applied at the subsequent start-up.  Auto-reload uses the Jenkins CLI
      # over SSH to reapply config when changes to the ConfigScripts are detected.  The admin user (or account you specify in
      # Master.AdminUser) will have a random SSH private key (RSA 4096) assigned unless you specify OwnSshKey: true.  This will be saved to a k8s secret.
      enabled: false
      image: shadwell/k8s-sidecar:0.0.2
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      resources:
        #   limits:
        #     cpu: 100m
        #     memory: 100Mi
        #   requests:
        #     cpu: 50m
        #     memory: 50Mi
      # SSH port value can be set to any unused TCP port.  The default, 1044, is a non-standard SSH port that has been chosen at random.
      # Is only used to reload jcasc config from the sidecar container running in the Jenkins master pod.
      # This TCP port will not be open in the pod (unless you specifically configure this), so Jenkins will not be
      # accessible via SSH from outside of the pod.  Note if you use non-root pod privileges (RunAsUser & FsGroup),
      # this must be > 1024:
      sshTcpPort: 1044
      # label that the configmaps with dashboards are marked with:
      label: jenkins_config
      # folder in the pod that should hold the collected dashboards:
      folder: /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs
      # If specified, the sidecar will search for dashboard config-maps inside this namespace.
      # Otherwise the namespace in which the sidecar is running will be used.
      # It's also possible to specify ALL to search in all namespaces:
      # searchNamespace:

    # Allows you to inject additional/other sidecars
    other:
    ## The example below runs the client for https://smee.io as sidecar container next to Jenkins,
    ## that allows to trigger build behind a secure firewall.
    ## https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/01/07/webhook-firewalls/#triggering-builds-with-webhooks-behind-a-secure-firewall
    ##
    ## Note: To use it you should go to https://smee.io/new and update the url to the generete one.
    # - name: smee
    #   image: docker.io/twalter/smee-client:1.0.2
    #   args: ["--port", "{{ .Values.Master.ServicePort }}", "--path", "/github-webhook/", "--url", "https://smee.io/new"]
    #   resources:
    #     limits:
    #       cpu: 50m
    #       memory: 128Mi
    #     requests:
    #       cpu: 10m
    #       memory: 32Mi
  # Node labels and tolerations for pod assignment
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
  # ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#taints-and-tolerations-beta-feature
  NodeSelector: {}
  Tolerations: {}
  PodAnnotations: {}

  # The below two configuration-related values are deprecated and replaced by Jenkins Configuration as Code (see above
  # JCasC key).  They will be deleted in an upcoming version.
  CustomConfigMap: false
  # By default, the configMap is only used to set the initial config the first time
  # that the chart is installed.  Setting `OverwriteConfig` to `true` will overwrite
  # the jenkins config with the contents of the configMap every time the pod starts.
  # This will also overwrite all init scripts
  OverwriteConfig: false

  ingress:
    enabled: false
    labels: {}
    annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    # Set this path to JenkinsUriPrefix above or use annotations to rewrite path
    # path: "/jenkins"
    tls:
    # - secretName: jenkins.cluster.local
    #   hosts:
    #     - jenkins.cluster.local
  AdditionalConfig: {}

  # Master.HostAliases allows for adding entries to Pod /etc/hosts:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/
  HostAliases: []
  # - ip: 192.168.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - something.local
  # - ip: 10.0.50.50
  #   hostnames:
  #     - other.local

Agent:
  Enabled: true
  Image: jenkins/jnlp-slave
  ImageTag: 3.27-1
  CustomJenkinsLabels: []
# ImagePullSecret: jenkins
  Component: "jenkins-slave"
  Privileged: false
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
    limits:
      cpu: "200m"
      memory: "256Mi"
  # You may want to change this to true while testing a new image
  AlwaysPullImage: false
  # Controls how slave pods are retained after the Jenkins build completes
  # Possible values: Always, Never, OnFailure
  PodRetention: Never
  # You can define the volumes that you want to mount for this container
  # Allowed types are: ConfigMap, EmptyDir, HostPath, Nfs, Pod, Secret
  # Configure the attributes as they appear in the corresponding Java class for that type
  # https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes
  # Pod-wide ennvironment, these vars are visible to any container in the slave pod
  envVars:
  # - name: PATH
  #   value: /usr/local/bin
  volumes:
  # - type: Secret
  #   secretName: mysecret
  #   mountPath: /var/myapp/mysecret
  NodeSelector: {}
  # Key Value selectors. Ex:
  # jenkins-agent: v1

  # Executed command when side container gets started
  Command:
  Args:
  # Side container name
  SideContainerName: jnlp
  # Doesn't allocate pseudo TTY by default
  TTYEnabled: false
  # Max number of spawned agent
  ContainerCap: 10
  # Pod name
  PodName: default

Persistence:
  Enabled: true
  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires Persistence.Enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  # ExistingClaim:
  ## jenkins data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  # StorageClass: "-"
  Annotations: {}
  AccessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  Size: 8Gi
  volumes:
  #  - name: nothing
  #    emptyDir: {}
  mounts:
  #  - mountPath: /var/nothing
  #    name: nothing
  #    readOnly: true

NetworkPolicy:
  # Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources.
  Enabled: false
  # For Kubernetes v1.4, v1.5 and v1.6, use 'extensions/v1beta1'
  # For Kubernetes v1.7, use 'networking.k8s.io/v1'
  ApiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

## Install Default RBAC roles and bindings
rbac:
  install: false
  serviceAccountName: default
  # Role reference
  roleRef: cluster-admin
  # Role kind (Role or ClusterRole)
  roleKind: ClusterRole
  # Role binding kind (RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding)
  roleBindingKind: ClusterRoleBinding

## Backup cronjob configuration
## Ref: https://github.com/nuvo/kube-tasks
backup:
  # Backup must use RBAC
  # So by enabling backup you are enabling RBAC specific for backup
  enabled: false
  # Schedule to run jobs. Must be in cron time format
  # Ref: https://crontab.guru/
  schedule: "0 2 * * *"
  annotations:
    # Example for authorization to AWS S3 using kube2iam
    # Can also be done using environment variables
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: jenkins
  image:
    repository: nuvo/kube-tasks
    tag: 0.1.2
  # Additional arguments for kube-tasks
  # Ref: https://github.com/nuvo/kube-tasks#simple-backup
  extraArgs: []
  # Add additional environment variables
  env:
  # Example environment variable required for AWS credentials chain
  - name: AWS_REGION
    value: us-east-1
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
      cpu: 1
  # Destination to store the backup artifacts
  # Supported cloud storage services: AWS S3, Minio S3, Azure Blob Storage
  # Additional support can added. Visit this repository for details
  # Ref: https://github.com/nuvo/skbn
  destination: s3://nuvo-jenkins-data/backup
```

My `requirements.yaml` file in the chart looks like

```
dependencies:
  - name: jenkins
    version: 0.35.1
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
  - name: istio-components
    version: 0.4.1
    repository: s3://helm-chart-repository/
```

I tried updating the plugin version under `InstallPlugins` and pushing helm chart and listing it (I can see it has been updated), but it had no effect on the error, like plugin is not updated at all.

Any advice how to proceed on debugging this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this issue by deleting the /plugins folder under /var/jenkins_home and then restarting my Jenkins pod. This created a new /plugins folder and then I no longer had any plugin dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

You must double-check the values. initializeOnce: true in yaml file

to initializeOnce: flase, then retry